# Placeholder padding doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to place padding for an input placeholder in FireFox and so far having no luck. I have tried using padding, text-indent and none work in FireFox for me. I have my code below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <div id='contact_form'>
            <input type='text' name='subject' placeholder='Subject' id='Subject' class='contactForm_keys' title='Subject' />

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#Subject{
    margin-left: 43px;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    width: 605px;
    height: 40px;
}

#Subject:focus, #Subject:hover{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}

/*input placeholder styling*/
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{font-size:14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; color:#c46457; padding-left: 15px;}
input:-moz-placeholder{font-size:14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; color:#c46457; line-height: normal;  padding: 0 10px 0 29px;} 
input::-moz-placeholder{font-size:14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; color:#c46457; line-height: normal;  padding: 0 10px 0 29px;} 
#contact_frm input:-ms-input-placeholder{font-size:14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; color:#c46457; padding-left: 15px;}
```

Comment: Just add a simple padding to the textbox.

Comment: why are you adding padding to placeholder just add padding to text box, for place holder you need to add placeholder.js

Comment: cheers, padding to the textbox fixes the problem. But why padding to the placeholder doesn't work in Firefox? I thought they fixed the bug and you could now just use placeholder tag?!

Comment: Firefox only seems to support color, opacity and background. As an alternative to giving the input a padding-left, you can put some spaces in the value of the placeholder attribute. `placeholder="   Subject"`.